# What are annihilators?

Tags: automata

I was recently listening to **Automata** lecture, there it was told told that an empty set is an **Annihilator** for concatenation just like $0$ is for multiplication. What do we mean by this statement?

Comment: In Algebra the Annihilator of some element is the set of all elements such that their product is $0$. This for sure is in integral domains a very small set but can be very large in rings which doesn't have such nice properties. In linear algebra the annihilator of some set is the set of all linearforms which evaluate constant zero on this set.

Comment: What @DominicMichaelis said means in particular that $A \circ \emptyset = \emptyset$, where $\circ$ is concatenation.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis can you please put some examples as I am not that well versed in mathematics right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a semigroup $S$ (denoted multiplicatively) an [*absorbing element*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element) or *annihilating element* or [*zero element*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Identity_and_zero) is an element $z$ of $S$ such that, for all $s \in S$, $zs = z = sz$.

In particular, the set of all languages is a semigroup under concatenation. This semigroup has a unique zero, namely the empty set, since 
the equality $L \emptyset = \emptyset =\emptyset L$ holds for each language $L$.